# Applying Rao-Blackwell to Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1, .., X_n$ be iid $N(\mu, 1)$. We want to estimate $\theta$ for $P(X_i < \lambda)$ for any $\lambda$.

Consider $U$ = 
 \begin{cases} 
      1 & X_i <= \lambda \\
      0 & X_I > \lambda  \\
   \end{cases}

$U(x, \theta)$ is inefficient. I want to Rao-Blackwellize $U$ by using $\bar{X}$ as my sufficient statistic. How would I go about doing this?

I think I need to find $E[U \mid \bar{X}$] but I am not sure if this is correct or where to go from here.

Comment: Avoid [cross-posting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/400063/119261).

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don´t give a reply [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3224768/mle-of-lambda-for-poisson-when-given-limited-information#3224768) and deleted the post?

Comment: I realized I kind of muddied up the question by not really knowing if it was a process or not, or even what that meant